# quickly compile cpp file

Tags: visual-studio

I work with Visual Studio 2008. Sometimes when i'm looking for certain small tools on the web, they are provided as single cpp files. I guess in linux it's very easy to build the tools using a single command (i'm no linux guy). So my question is, what's the quickest way to compile them under windows (which Visual Studio 2008 installed). Do I really need to create a new project and add this cpp file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link below outlines the exact steps on how to do this from the VS command line. It's specific to VS2005, but it should work the same way in VS2008.

[Compile a Native C++ Program from the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are not linux guy as you said you can still use the gcc/g++ compiler to compile your cpp code with a single line on Windows.
Just make sure that your code does not explicitly depend on microsoft specifics, then you can install mingw once and then all you have to to is:

g++ test.cpp -o test.exe

and you get your tool ready.